# htaccess rewrite all image requests from a non-existent folder to folder-name.jpg

Tags: image, .htaccess, url-rewriting, directory

Here's what I am trying to do, for example . . .

```
http://www.website.com/images/folder-with-a-crazy-name/any-image-at-all.jpg
```

would rewrite to . . .

```
http://www.website.com/images/folder-with-a-crazy-name.jpg
```

Does this make sense?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a variable? I mean, _/images/a/any-image-at-all.jpg_ will be rewritten into _/images/a.jpg_, either _/images/b/any-image-at-all.jpg_ to _/images/b.jpg_, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rewrite all jpeg image files in a folder to that folder with `.jpg` appended

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.+?)/[^/]+?\.jpg$ /images/$1.jpg [L]
```

Comment: and what about url `example.com/uploads/image/7474/23b3825eb250bc00e900142996b4d398_600.jpg` to another folder but with same hierarchy ?

Comment: @user1954544 Such a URL won't match this rule, unless the .htaccess file is in the uploads directory. Ask a separate question, if you don't find an answer in the existing questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just paste this into your *.htaccess* file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^images/([a-z0-9-_]+)/any-image-at-all.jpg /images/$1.jpg
```

Or if you want even the other image formats to be rewritten, then just replace the third and the last line on the code above with this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^images/([a-z0-9-_]+)/any-image-at-all.([a-z0-9]{3}|[a-z0-9]{4}) /images/$1.$2
```

If the the folder *images* is also a variable, then try one of the following rules below:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/any-image-at-all.jpg /$1/$2.jpg
```

If the file extension is a variable, then try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/any-image-at-all.([a-z0-9]{3}|[a-z0-9]{4}) /$1/$2.$3
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.  But the image "folder-name/any-image-at-all.jpg" was suppost to represent that the image could have any name.  For example "folder-name/this-is-another-image.jpg" would both rewrite to "folder-name.jpg".