# Mod_rewrite - change image names to product names

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the product page:

> mywebsite.com/product_name.html

On this page I have product image which is sent by a third party software and consists of checksum. So it looks like this:

> mywebsite.com/images/detailed/11/34dc5fdbc74bce8164edde2d9afc8e2c.jpg

Is there any way to use mod_rewrite to change the image name 34dc5fdbc74bce8164edde2d9afc8e2c.jpg to product_name.jpg?

Comment: What exactly do you want??? I didn't understand... And, have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I need something similar to this: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839426/htaccess-rewrite-all-image-requests-from-a-non-existent-folder-to-folder-name-jp[/link]

Comment: I use SEO addon but without it the link structure looks like this: >http://mywebsite.com/index.php?dispatch=products.view&product_id=34619 I wonder if I can somehow change the image name for SEO purposes to have the same name as the product.

Comment: Main problem I see here is that the URL of the image have no reference to the product so it would be pretty hard to give it a product_name if you can't use any of the URL that leads to the image. You would need to redirect the images to a php file and serve it from there by taking the product ID and giving it a name.

Comment: Is it even possible to look up for the id of the product using mod_rewrite and change the name of the image to product name? Sorry for silly questions, I really need this done and have no clue where to start. Thanks for any help!